# Windows Smart Screen pops up after EV Code Signing

Tags: windows, digital-signature, code-signing

I am code signing my application's installer using an EV Code Signing that we have bought recently at work. The code signing is performed when the installer is created using Inno Setup (version 5.6.1).

It seems to work correctly and I can see the certificate in the digital signatures tab in the installer's file properties. But after downloading it from the server, windows smart screen alert always shows up stating "Windows protected your PC".

I am not sure why this is happening and if I am doing something incorrectly?

I have seen [another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139347/smart-screen-filter-still-complains-despite-i-signed-the-executable-why?noredirect=1&lq=1) and its answers do not solve my problem. It is stated there that EV code signing certificates do not have to go through the trust/reputation building phase.

Comment: May I know which Certificate Authority you use to buy your certificate?

Comment: We have bought the certificate from Sectigo (formerly Comodo CA).

Comment: That's wired. I confirmed Sectigo Code Signing Root Cert is in MS's Trust Root Program AND my Windows 10 machine. I will advise you to contact Sectigo for technical help.