# Switching CSC certificate issuer and SmartScreen

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, code-signing, authenticode

We have most of our SSL certificates hosted at GoDaddy but have Standard Code signing certificate from GlobalSign, we would like to switch to GoDaddy CSC since our CSC from GlobalSign is expiring in 3 months.

How would this affect MS SmartScreen, would we have to build our "reputation" again? Or does MS only care about name of entity that signed application and not the issuer?

Also would we have issues with signing applications with both certificates in transition period since our GlobalSign certificate is still valid?

Comment: Relevant? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222140/transferring-microsoft-smartscreen-reputation-to-renewed-certificate

Comment: @schroeder Yes I think that answers first part of the question.